# Option Strict On issues where generic type isn't known until runtime

Tags: vb.net, type-parameter, option-strict

I have the following code that has worked fine for months, but I forgot to create this class with `Option Strict On` so now I am going back to clean up my code correctly, however I haven't been able to figure out a way around the following issue.

I have a local variable declared like this:

```
Private _manageComplexProperties
```

Now with option strict, this isn't allowed due to no `As` clause which I understand, however the reason that it is like this is because the instance of the class that will be assigned to it takes a type parameter which isn't known until run time. This is solved by the following code:

```
Private _type As Type
*SNIP OTHER IRRELEVANT VARIABLES*

Public Sub Show()

    Dim requiredType As Type = _
        GetType(ManageComplexProperties(Of )).MakeGenericType(_type)

    _manageComplexProperties = Activator.CreateInstance(requiredType, _
         New Object() {_value, _valueIsList, _parentObject, _unitOfWork})

    _result = _manageComplexProperties.ShowDialog(_parentForm)
    If _result = DialogResult.OK Then
        _resultValue = _manageComplexProperties.GetResult()
    End If

End Sub
```

Again option strict throws a few errors due to late binding, but they should be cleared up with a cast once I can successfully declare the `_manageComplexProperties` variable correctly, but I can't seem to get a solution that works due to the type parameter not known until run time. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare your variable as `Object`

```
Private _manageComplexProperties as Object
```

And then you will have to persist with reflection, e.g. to call `ShowDialog` method:

```
Dim method As System.Reflection.MethodInfo = _type.GetMethod("ShowDialog")
_result = method.Invoke(_manageComplexProperties, New Object() {_parentForm})
```

Comment: If I do that, I still can't cast `_manageComplexProperties` variable in the `Show()` method to anything so I can use the `.ShowDialog()` or `.GetResult()` methods. I am beginning to think that you can't use `Option Strict On` in this situation!

Comment: Can't you use `DirectCast(_manageComplexProperties, YourType)`? OK. you can't. A sec...

Comment: You will need to use reflection until the end, I'm afraid. See my edit for an example.

Comment: With a little extra work regarding properties rather than methods, getting the correct overload and casting, my code now works as it did before, thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `option infer on` on the top of your vb file. It enables local `type inference`.

Using this option allows you to use `Dim` without the "As" clausule, it is like
`var` in C#.

IntelliSense when Option Infer and Option Strict are off

[image]

IntelliSense when Option Infer is on (as you can see it has type inference)

[image]

If you do not want to use option infer on, you will have to declare the variable matching the type of the one returned by  `Activator.CreateInstance`

Comment: I don't think this is working for me, either that or I am misunderstanding something which is entirely possible! In effect I need to declare the variable like this: `Private _manageComplexProperties = ManageComplexProperties(Of )`, however it needs a type in the declaration, which I don't know at that point.